# java bash command problem

Tags: java, bash, exit-code, runtime.exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the bash command exit code from a Process run from within Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886935/how-do-i-get-the-bash-command-exit-code-from-a-process-run-from-within-java)

Hi, I have a program which is a simple decrypts another file using bash command `./nv0914 < nv0914.challenge` where nv0914 is a unix executable file and nv0914.challenge is a text file used for decryption. Now when i am running it from bash and just after that if I run the command `echo ${?}` I am getting a value 0, which is good. But now I have to implement an attack and for that I need to get the exit value printed through a java program. I have this code as if now:

```
import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class ExecBashCommand {
     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


       Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
       Process process = runtime.exec("./nv0914 < nv0914.challenge");

      /* InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
       String line;*/

System.out.println("Exit Code: "+process.exitValue()); 
       //System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:", Arrays.toString(args));

      /* while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }*/

     }
    }
```

But this program is giving me an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process hasn't exited
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.exitValue(UNIXProcess.java:172)
        at ExecBashCommand.main(ExecBashCommand.java:16)
```

Any suggestions as to how to get the exit value. Thanks

Comment: You should see Peter's answer in your previous identical question.  It contains the answer.  You should also accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried calling `process.waitFor()` before you try and read the exit value?

Comment: Its just giving me an empty terminal... as if its running a infinite loop.